# Siebel popups can't be closed by X button (after a popup is opened for the second time)

Tags: siebel

Siebel popups in High Interactivity can't be closed by 'X' button in the upper right corner of the popup window (after a popup is opened for the second time). Is there any way to enable it?

To reproduce that:

1. open Help->About View... can be closed by X button
2. open Help->About View... now it can NOT be closed by X button

   - siebel version: 8.1.1.14
   - Internet Explorer 11, compatibility mode enabled

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not a usual behaviour. It may occurs if you are using IE version other than IE8. Which IE version you are using ? If you are using IE version > IE8 then enable compatibility mode and try again.

Comment: Thanks. I added more detailed description. We use IE11, compatibility mode enabled. The problem occurs after a popup is opened for the second time.

Comment: Compatibility mode helps in IE10 mostly. For IE11 you will face many other issues like Field name not found etc. Specially if you are Siebel developer, downgrade to IE8.